# Unitary operator statement

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unitary-matrices

I encountered this statement in the book
$$W(U^{*}TU)=W(T)$$ for any unitary U where $W(T)$ is the numerical range. Definition of the numerical range is $$W(T)=\{\langle Tx,x\rangle |x\in H,\|x\|=1\}$$
I know that $U$ is unitary which means
$$UU^{*}=I=U^{*}U$$
Trying to prove this should go like this
$\langle U^{*}TUx,x\rangle =\langle TUx,Ux\rangle =\langle Ux,T^{*}Ux\rangle =\langle x,U^{*}T^{*}Ux\rangle $ and I dont know how to proceed here. It should simplify to just $\langle Tx,x\rangle $...I think...

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you have is that $\|Ux\|=1$ if and only if $\|x\|=1$. So the unitary is an automorphism of the set $\{x:\ \|x\|=1\}$. Hence
\begin{align}
W(T)&=\{\langle Tx,x\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&=\{\langle TUx,Ux\rangle:\ \|Ux\|=1\}\\
&=\{\langle TUx,Ux\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&=\{\langle U^*TUx,x\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&=W(U^*TU).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I ask a question.
From line 1 to line 2 we went because of the set equality of $x$ and $Ux$. And Second to third line , how can we just change set $Ux$ to $x$ and not swap it back. Is it because Unitary is an isomorphism so it doesnt change the structure,norm and the value given by the dot product?

Comment: It's just that $\|Ux\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$.